# Data not being sent via XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript

I have a weird issue with a script I am using to send some info to my PHP. I say weird because this code is a direct copy of some already working code on the same application, with new variable names. I need to upload a small amount of data to my server, and while the value is there and the code runs all the way through, the POST data is not being sent or something. I have checked, and it says it has been submitted to my PHP with the value but nothing happens. I am using Vue.js if there are questions about some of my formatting

I have tried looking at other examples online, but my thing is that this was a block of code that copied from a working part of my application. It works until the data transfer from JS -- PHP

JS

```
editDisplayName: function() {
      var self = this;
      var newName = prompt("10 Characters Max, 3 Min", "Enter Display Name");
      if(newName.length <= 10 && newName.length >= 3 ) {
          var sendData = new XMLHttpRequest();
          sendData.open("POST", "primary.php", true);
          sendData.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
          sendData.send(newName);
          self.username = window.localStorage.getItem('username');
          window.localStorage.clear();
      }
  }
```

PHP

```
function changeUsername() {
     // Connect to Server
     $link = // Commented Out For Security;
     if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
         die ("DB Connection Error");
     }
     $newName = $_POST['newName'];
     $newName = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $newName);
     $token = $_COOKIE['validToken'];
     $token = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $token);
     $query = "UPDATE userData SET username = '$newName' WHERE token = '$token' LIMIT 1";
     mysqli_query($link, $query);
     mysqli_close($link);
     echo("
         <script>
             var username = $newName;
             window.localStorage.setItem('username', username);
         </script>
     ");
 }
 if(isset($_POST['newName'])) {
     changeUsername();
 }
```

I'm expecting on my DOM that I would have the new username set, instead it is blank. The spot where stuff stops working is somewhere with the POST data being sent, since my PHP isn't picking anything up, but I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Your PHP assumes that the sent parameter is called `newName`. Are you specifying this anywhere in the js? I might be missing it, but what I see is `sendData.send(newName);` without a parameter name.

Comment: @AnisR. I have var newName but I don't think that is what you are meaning. Sorry if I am missing something, I am newer to working with JS for more than really simple things

Comment: @AnisR. Should I use a object and turn it into a JSON string for the transfer? I only have the one value to pass but could this be the issue?

Comment: Try following the answer I just posted, and let me know if this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just sending the value, *you should send the parameter name as well*.

So, instead of using `sendData.send(newName);`, try using:

```
sendData.send("newName=" + newName);
```

(as your Content-type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`)

**Or if you want to use JSON:**

Change your Content-type to `application/json`, then send the data as a JSON string, like so:

```
sendData.send(JSON.stringify({'newName': newName}));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm unsure as to why I didn't have that there, my save script has it so yeah. Again, thank you!